# how is an integration testing properly done with hibernate 3 spring 3.0.5 with spring transaction management(maven project)

Tags: hibernate, spring, maven-2, jakarta-ee, integration-testing

I believe this kind of question is being asked over and over again.but i think there is something here that i need to understand once for all.

I must admit that i'm very bad at undertanding how spring transactionmanagement works, but i thought i got what an integration test means till now where i'm completely confused.

here is how i write my integration test (i prefere the integration test to unit test when i come to test the data layer of an application, maybe a bad habit)

i autowire the objects , add the their properties in `setup()` and persist them there for later use for example with methods like `getUser()` or `findUser/findAll()` and then delete all of them in teardown. i think this has worked before when i open and close transaction myself.

i decide to give a try to the transactional annotation of the spring transactionmanagement.

**Problem 1**
when i don't add the model user to the context the test fails because i believe component-to-scan is not working:
 this is the error

> No matching bean of type [com.myproject.perso.admintest.model.User] found for   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this   dependency. Dependency annotations: 
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

i then have to uncomment it, same for the dao

**problem 2**

when there is only single test (testGetUser) and i have only `createUser(user1)` in `setup` and `delete(user1)` in `teardown`. the test is succesfull.Even with the same config in setup and teardown but this time with testFindUser it's still successfull with data in database and then deleted with teardown ok. but once i uncomment createUser(user2) in setup and delete(user2) in teardown in addition to the use1 create and delete then it throws this

> could not insert: [com.myproject.perso.admintest.model.User]; SQL [insert into users (email, password, username) values (?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:

i understand it has to do with the session not been flushed (even though i dont get it very well) by reading other's post but my question is when does spring transction come in?

**Questions**
**1** is something wrong with my test?
**2** if i want to keep my approach by creating POJO in the test as opposed to using DBUnit for example for fixtures how should i create this test.
**3** what spring transaction management does in all this then. thanks

here are my codes

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:WEB-INF/testadmin-webapp-config.xml"})
 public class UserDAOImplTest {


private UserDAO userDao;
@Autowired
public void setDao(UserDAO userDao){
   this.userDao = userDao;
}

@Autowired
User user1;

@Autowired
User user2;

public UserDAOImplTest() {
}

@Before
public void setUp() {

    user1.setEmail("user1@somemail.com");
    user1.setPassword("mypass");
    user1.setUsername("user1");

    user2.setEmail("user2@somemail.com");
    user2.setPassword("password");
    user2.setUsername("user2");

    userDao.createUser(user1);
    userDao.createUser(user2);
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    userDao.delete(user1);
    userDao.delete(user2);
}



/**
 * Test of getUser method, of class UserDAOImpl.
 */
@Test
public void testGetUser() {
    System.out.println("getUser test");

    User expResult = user1;
    User result = userDao.getUser(user1.getId());

    Assert.assertEquals(expResult.getId(), result.getId());
    Assert.assertEquals(expResult.getEmail(), result.getEmail());


    }

  @Test
  public void testFindUser() {
    System.out.println("findUser");
    Assert.assertTrue(true);

  }
}
```

my DAO interface look so

```
public interface UserDAO {

User getUser(Long userId);
User findUser(String name);
List<User> getAllUsers();
void createUser(User user);
void delete(User user);
void updateUser(User user);

}
```

it's implementation is like so:

```
@Repository("UserDAO")
@Transactional
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}

@Override
public User getUser(Long userId) {
   return hibernateTemplate.get(User.class, userId);
}

@Override
public User findUser(String username) {
   List found=  hibernateTemplate.find("from User u where u.username= ?", username);
   return (found.size() == 1) ? (User) found.get(0) : new User();
}

//......

@Override
@Transactional
public void createUser(User user) {
     hibernateTemplate.save(user);
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
public void delete(User user) {
    hibernateTemplate.delete(user);
}
```

//.....

```
my User POJO is like so

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long Id;
@Column(name="username" ,unique=true)
private String username;
@Column(name="password")
private String password;
@Column(name="email", unique=true)
private String email;
```

here is my test context file

```
<!-- for i left out some part in order to be concise  -->
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject.perso.abmintest" />
<bean id="datasource"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
  <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
  <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
  <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"  />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myproject.perso.admintest.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties" >
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Model Section-->
<!--<bean id="user" class="com.myproject.admintest.model.User" />-->

<!-- Model Section End-->
<!--DAO-->
<!--<bean id="userDao" class="com.myproject.admintest.dao.UserDAOImpl" />-->

<!--DAO end -->
```

here is my pom :

```
org.springframework (most of spring stuff including spring-asm)3.0.5.RELEASE
org.hibernate:hibernate-core 3.6.1.Final
org.hibernate:hibernate-cglig-repack 2.1_3
log4j:log4j1.2.14
org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12 1.5.2
junit:junit 4.5
commons-collections:commons-collections 3.2.1
jboss:javassist 3.7.ga 
commons-logging:commons-logging 1.1.1
```

full pom can be found [here](http://pastie.org/1671318)

Answer (score 2):

just make it simple buddy

```
@Autowired
private UserDAO userDao;

private User user1;

private User user2;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    user1 = new User();
    user1.setEmail("user1@somemail.com");
    user1.setPassword("mypass");
    user1.setUsername("user1");

    user2 = new User();
    user2.setEmail("user2@somemail.com");
    user2.setPassword("password");
    user2.setUsername("user2");
}
```

It would be better if put create user the test method

```
@Test
public void testGetUser() {
    userDao.create(user1);

    User expResult = user1;
    User result = userDao.getUser(user1.getId());

    Assert.assertEquals(expResult.getId(), result.getId());
    Assert.assertEquals(expResult.getEmail(), result.getEmail());


}
```

You can add @TransactionConfiguration to rollback your transaction such as Create Update Delete operation.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:WEB-INF/testadmin-webapp-config.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)
```

Comment: thanks for the example adisembiring, really appreciate it. i do have one question, though, how would you test for collections say, `testGetAll()` how to provide data in the database before testing that one.In fact that's one of the reason why i save some of the test objects in the `setUp()` method and clear them in the teardown. thanks again

Comment: put userDao.create(user1); in the body at test method, and then use your dao to find user by the user id.
You ca use 
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)
to rollback user that you save, It will return your database in the first state before you run the test. so you doesn't need to use tearDown to remove user

Answer (score 1):

Don't auto wire the user objects create then in the setup method.

If you add @Transactional annotation to the test class - spring will start a transaction before running the test (& setup method)- run the test as a part of the transaction and then rollback the transaction.  This way you don't have to write code in the tearDown method to explicitly delete the objects(undo things done in the setup).

You will have to call flush / clear on the session - by getting a reference to SessionFactory injected into the test to force the queries to be fired & the object re-fetched from the database.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i know get what you are trying to say.i must admit it's not clear enough. 
you said ". This way you don't have to write code in the tearDown method to explicitly delete the objects(undo things done in the setup)." that means creating new object for and inside each test?